# Express + Jade: render an array of partials

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, partials

**I have** partial `button` that looks like:

```
.button button.custom_button(type='button', value='', onclick=#{functionName}) #{functionName}
```

And I render partials with help of `res.renderPartials` function which comes from `npm install express-partial`.

And **I want to** render it on user request. So I have controller method like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/buttons', function(req, res) {
    var funcs = ['func1();', 'func2();', 'func3()', .... ]; // where funcs.length > 15

    res.renderPartials({    
        // PROBLEM #1: how to make this in a loop
        // PROBLEM #2: why do it returns only the func[28] rendering result
        'partials/button': {functionName: funcs[0]},
        'partials/button': {functionName: funcs[1]},
        ..........
        'partials/button': {functionName: funcs[28]},
    });
});
```

**Question:** *how to render all button partials at once?* Mean pass array to `res.renderPartials` and avoid encountering each button separated by comma.

**P.S.** I supposed that's possible because in Jade template we can do this:

```
- each video in videos
   !=partial('partials/video', {title:video.title, artist:video.artist})
```

Example is taken from [here](http://www.hacksparrow.com/express-js-jade-partials-how-to-use-them.html)

Comment: I don't see `res.renderPartials` in the 4.x documentation. Is it from somewhere else?

Comment: @Scimonster I found it here https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-partial. Pls point me the new way to do so

Comment: No, that's fine if it's from an external module. You just might want say so in the question, so people like me don't have to go "what's `res.renderPartials`?"

Comment: @Scimonster no prob - updated my question

Comment: @V_B I would suggest [submitting new feature request](https://github.com/uber/express-partial/issues/new) to [`express-partial` issues tracker](https://github.com/uber/express-partial/issues).

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny look at my asnwer pls. Looks like I know the solution

Answer (score 0):

I though in my case we can use embedded partials, like

*buttons.jade*

```
- each func in #{functions}
   !=partial('partials/button', {functionName:func})
```

*button.jade*

```
.button button.custom_button(type='button', value='', onclick=#{functionName}) #{functionName}
```

*router*

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/buttons', function(req, res) {
    res.renderPartials({    
        'partials/buttons': {functions: ['func1();', 'func2();', 'func3()', .... ]}
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a workaround. It solves your particular problem, but not a general problem of rendering multiple partials with the same template.